# Is there any program that I can use to edit files on my raspberry pi from a remote location

Tags: node.js, npm, ssh, filesystems

I have a nodejs sever constantly running on an rpi4b 4gb running raspbian. What I would like to do is use an online website to edit local files from anywhere. I already am using dataplicity, but the problem with this is I have to edit files slowly through command line because of it being similar in style to ssh. An online program similar to dataplicity that has a built-in text editor? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using Visual Studio Code remotely? I use it to remotely develop on my Raspberry Pi. Check out these instructions for getting it to work:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/visual-studio-code-remote-development-over-ssh-to-a-raspberry-pi-is-butter

Comment: I actually figured out how to host a GUI for text editing via dataplicity. Sorry for the late response and thanks for the help!